A variant of $k$-nim
Consider the following two-player game. There are $k$ piles of chips of sizes $n_1,\ldots,n_k$. The two players take turns. In each turn, a player can
remove an arbitrary positive number of chips from at most two piles (there is no restriction on how much from each pile). The player who takes the last chip wins. What are the $P$- and $N$-positions in this game?
So far I've only found the trivial ones: having $1$ or $2$ piles of non-zero size are clearly $N$-positions, so is $(1,1,1,1)$, while $(1,1,1)$ isn't. However, brute force isn't going to find all of them, so there should be a pattern I can't find. Any help is appreciated!
